# Intercepting http resource request to modify headers

Tags: javascript, http, browser, static, intercept

I have a use case where I want to intercept all http resource request and modify the request headers. Intercepting XMLHttpRequest is fine but I need to intercept resource requests from my JS code. Has anyone ever done that?

Ex : GET https://something.com/demo.js

While requesting for this resource I want to intercept the request and add authentication header information.

Comment: Depends on what you use to make requests. For example using axios it has built-in interceptor. https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: Axios intercepts XMLHttpRequest requests and not resouce requests.

Comment: Post your example of resource request please